# Executing a jQuery script for each file and then print the results, BUT getting the first result multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, function, select

I'm trying to get the first link of each page using `$('.yuRUbf a')[0].href;`, however, this code gets the data of all pages, and then prints the link of the first page multiple times.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php 

function pageNum($pageNum) {

  include $pageNum.".html";

?>
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      const el = $('.yuRUbf a')[0].href;
      console.log(el);
    });
    </script>
<?php 

}


pageNum("1");
pageNum("2");

 ?>
```

EDIT:

Let me explain in another way: I have 5 html pages, each html page includes 10 links, I want the first link of each html page.

So I used the jQuery script to extract the href attribute value which is the link, however, instead of extracting the first link of each page, it is extracting the first link of the first page 5 times as I have 5 files.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? How is this related to PHP?

Comment: Using a php function to read file contents, I tried looping and functions, searched for a method to remove the file after it being executed but found it is not possible.

Comment: Can you (also) provided the *rendered* output - guessing what it looks like in the browser is just a guess.

Comment: *then prints the link of the first page multiple times* - because you include the script in the `pageNum` php function and then call it "multiple times".   Take it out of `pageNum` if you only want to call it once.

Comment: I don't want to call it once, let me explain in another way:
I have 5 html pages, each html page includes 10 links, I want the first link of each html page.

Comment: You can only show 1 HTML page at a time, so @freedomn-m's approach is correct.

Comment: So I used the jQuery script to extract the href attribute value which is the link, however, instead of extracting the first link of each page, it is extracting the first link of the first page 5 times as I have 5 files.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (and edit).  Is there anything that separates/distinguishes each `include $pageNum.".html"` page?  I'm assuming not `<html>` or `<body>` as these should only be once, but each of your `1.html`/`2.html` might have at the top `<div class='yuRUbf'>` - if that's the case (or if you can edit it so that it or similar is the case) then you can use `$(".yuRUbf").map((i,e)=>$(e).find("a")[0].href).get()`

Comment: You *could* (but I don't recommend it as a viable solution) change your existing code to `const el = $('.yuRUbf:last a')[0].href;` **without** the `doc.ready` - so that it runs inline.  Then, the code runs as soon as it appears while parsing the document and the `:last` will be the "current" page that's just been rendered/included.   But it's a terrible way to run javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the existing code returns links for all pages, I'll assume that each "page" contains something similar to

```
<div class='yuRUbf'>
...
<div>
```

In this case, you can collate all the first links into an array using a single call at the end (ie not inside the pageNum loop)

```
var links = $(".yuRUbf").map((i,e) => $(e).find("a")[0].href).toArray()
```

(if you're passing this to something else, eg `links.addClass("active")` then don't use the `.toArray()`)

this is the equivalent of, if you prefer/need a loop rather than an array:

```
$(".yuRUbf").each(function(i, e) {
  var el = $(this).find("a")[0].href;
  console.log(el);
});
```

Example:

```js
$(function() {
    const first_links = $(".yuRUbf").map((i,e)=>$(e).find("a")[0].href).get();
    console.log(first_links)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='yuRUbf'>
  <div>
    <a href='l1'>l1</a>
  </div>
  <a href='l2'>l2></a>
  <a href='l2'>l2</a>
</div>
<div class='yuRUbf'>
  <div>
    <a href='l12'>l12</a>
  </div>
  <a href='l22'>l22></a>
  <a href='l22'>l22</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was just experimenting with your solution in the previous comment, It actually solved half of the problem, but I can find solutions on my own for the remaining problems.

Comment: *I can find solutions on my own for the remaining problems* that's the best way :)

Comment: Each page has 10 <div class='yuRUbf'>, and each class includes a single link, so I can solve the rest by some manual work! Thanks again.